# Can not restart Postgresql on BigSur

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, macos-big-sur

My installed postgresql (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql/13.2_1) crashed and I can't find a way to start again:

```
==> Successfully started `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)
➜  ~ brew services list

LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist

postgresql error   *** /Users/***/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist

5432 is not running..
```

Reinstalling does not help.
Any Idea?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to ask this question.

Comment: may be.. I downgraded to --v 12x.. works so far.. May be 13 is buggy.